# How to calculate correlation with condition from different variable?

Tags: r, correlation

I want to calculate the correlation between sf and pf only for values correspond to half of (highest values) P

```
  P=c(1,6,5,6,2,8,5)
  sf=c(1,2,6,6,4,5,5)
  Pf=c(1,6,5,8,4,8,5)
  cor(sf,Pf)
```

Any help please?

Comment: Looks like trivial problem. See question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760284/how-to-calculate-correlation-in-r?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this should do the trick

```
cor(sf[P > median(P)], Pf[P > median(P)])
```

Since you want the top 50% of `P`, this corresponds to the values of P greater than the median.

Comment: Did *you* try it on *this* data? I get `[1] 0.9707253` on the data you posted.